# Does git run "fetch" automatically, or only when I tell it to?

Tags: git

I'm using git in bash, and I have one of those fancy bash prompts that gives me some repository information without having to type `git status`. It tells me which branch I'm on, how many modified and untracked files, and, relevant to this question, how far ahead/behind the remote I am.

Recently I've begun to notice something strange: often when I press enter and a new prompt appears, it suddenly tells me I'm a few commits behind master. And, in fact, I am, "git status" confirms it. But my question is: how does it know? At no point did I run `git fetch` or `git pull` or any other command that would talk to the remote and find out how far/behind my local checkout was. In fact, I've seen it happen where I'm fairly certain I haven't run any git commands in between, except for `git status -z --porcelain` which my bash prompt script runs to generate the prompt.

It's freaking me out a bit. I mean, the information is certainly helpful, but the idea of something running git commands on my repository without me knowing about it is a bit unsettling. So here are my questions:

1. Does git do this kind of thing? Run fetches automatically in the background as a result of running some other command? Obviously, push/pull needs to run a fetch to execute, but I'm talking about "local" commands like `git status`, `git add`, `git commit`, `git diff`, etc.
2. Is there any kind of "command log" in git, where I can audit which operations were run, when, and by whom?

Comment: Forgot to include: I'm running macOS, and use the stock git that comes with Xcode command line tools, version 2.11.0.

Comment: Are you using _any_ other tools that are git-aware? For example, I know that Tower for Mac will do a fetch occasionally. If you have any other git tools or git-aware tools, one of them could be doing the same.

Comment: I just checked, and the only other thing is SourceTree which I have installed. But it's not running. Maybe it has installed some service or something to run regular fetches. I'll see if I can find out if that's the thing.

Comment: Do you work in that repository with Xcode? I could imagine Xcode (like most UI Git tools I have used) would automatically fetch. SourceTree does this when running.

Comment: What tool are you using to have the fancy bash prompts ? Have you coded this script by yourself ? if yes can you post the code ?

Comment: @crashmstr no, i don't use Xcode. the tools for this particular project is the Unity game engine and Vim. Maybe it's a vim plugin doing it?

Comment: @obounaim i use a script i wrote myself, you can find it in my dot-files repo here: https://github.com/OskarSigvardsson/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/bash_prompt.py it's not really meant for public consumption though. there are other, more mature versions around, like this one: https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell

Comment: Try to replace the script by a simple bash command "git status -z --porcelain" and then watch if you still face the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using git in bash, and I have one of those fancy bash prompts that gives me some repository information without having to type git status.

This seems the most likely culprit, by far. [Magicmonty](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt) is one example of a git prompt script that runs `git fetch` (see `gitprompt.sh`). I bet you'll find the culprit if you look through the script that sets your prompt.

Comment: I wrote the bash prompt script myself, it only calls the status command i specified. It's part of my dotfiles repo, here: https://github.com/OskarSigvardsson/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/bash_prompt.py (it's pretty rough, not really meant for public consumption, but there it is)

Answer (score 0):

1. Nope, it does not
2. Not that I know of. What you can do is to set the environment variable `GIT_TRACE`, then Git tells you which commands it internally calls.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you (or someone else) has set up something special on your machine to make it run fetches, it doesn't.  The "ahead/behind" count is a comparison of your local branch to the remote reference as updated by the last communication with the server.

So how to explain it?  Since it probably has to do with something curious to your installation, I can at best pose speculations.

Certainly I work in multiple windows, so sometimes my prompt in one is stale because I've been working in another, and hitting ENTER updates it.  Of course you'd probably *know* if you were doing this... but a similar case (that should never happen, but I can't rule out from only my knowledge of your system) - if your local repo is in shared storage and another user is working with it as well, you could be seeing the results of their work.  (If that's the case, I strongly advise you to get each developer working on a distinct repo that only that one developer accesses; that's exactly what clones are for.  But like I said, it's all just speculation anyway...)

The other obvious possibility would be if someone thought it might be helpful to have fetch run at scheduled intervals in the background.  I would find this aggravating personally, but I can imagine it happening and it would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: The repo isn't shared by anyone, it's just on my local drive. I thought it might be something like the "multiple windows" thing myself, that I'd just forgotten running a fetch or pull or something, but it's happened enough that I can't imagine that being the reason. I don't know what about my installation could be doing this, but I will investigate.